# Neural Networks: Garson's algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, deep-learning, neural-network

I am using Garson's algorithm to extract the relative importance of each variable fed to my neural network using the gar.fun() function in R, I get when using this function a plot as a result (see below) but I would also like to extract the numerical values from this function as well. How can this be done?

The used data can be found [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/student+performance).

The code:

```
library(neuralnet)
library(devtools)
source_gist('6206737')

trainset <- data[1:300, ]
testset <- data[301:395, ]

nn <- neuralnet(Pass ~ ., data=trainset, hidden=c(16,14,10,5), stepmax = 13000, linear.output=FALSE, err.fct = "ce")

gar.fun('y', nn)
```

The output:

[image: al Networ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot get your data or reproduce your plot, but using the example from [the website](https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/variable-importance-in-neural-networks/) where you got the code:

```
require(clusterGeneration)
require(nnet)

set.seed(2)
num.vars<-8
num.obs<-10000

cov.mat<-genPositiveDefMat(num.vars,covMethod=c("unifcorrmat"))$Sigma
rand.vars<-mvrnorm(num.obs,rep(0,num.vars),Sigma=cov.mat)
colnames(rand.vars) = paste0("col",1:ncol(rand.vars))
parms<-runif(num.vars,-10,10)
y<-rand.vars %*% matrix(parms) + rnorm(num.obs,sd=20)

y<-data.frame((y-min(y))/(max(y)-min(y)))
names(y)<-'y'
rand.vars<-data.frame(rand.vars)
mod1<-nnet(rand.vars,y,size=8,linout=T)

plotdata = gar.fun('y',mod1)
```

Values of y are :

```
plotdata$data
        rel.imp x.names
col5 -1.0000000    col5
col4 -0.9699018    col4
col6 -0.8217886    col6
col1  0.0000000    col1
col7  0.3600374    col7
col8  0.4018898    col8
col3  0.6114887    col3
col2  0.9299521    col2
```

And you can see them on the plot:

```
plotdata + geom_text(aes(label=round(rel.imp,3)),vjust=rep(c(2,-1.5),c(4,4)))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome @StupidWolf, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

a more accurate method is described in this paper
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-comparison-of-methods-for-assessing-the-relative-Hassan-Ibrahim/f04e8585f2ce70a127acc5f63c70ce785c9b4fbf#citing-papers
this method was developed by me
this is a code in R to compute relative importance 
bu it is used with one hidden layer

```
sqdif<-(nn$weights[[1]][[1]][-1,]-nn$startweights[[1]][[1]][-1,])^2
for(i in 1:(ncol(mydata)-1)){
  tabl[1,i]<-sum(sqdif[i,])/sum(sqdif)
  print(tabl[1,i])
}
```